# Send HTTP 204 response with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm creating an API using Google Cloud Endpoints where I would like to return a "no content" HTTP 204 response if there's nothing to return. I tried returning null, which throws an error on the development server, and a non-empty result on production with status code 200.

It is possible to send out a true 204 empty response or other types or custom responses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return a `204 No Content` for a production Python Cloud Endpoints API, you can use `VoidMessage`.

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote

class MyMessage(messages.Message):
  ...

@endpoints.api('someapi', 'v1', 'Description')
class MyApi(remote.Service):

  @endpoints.method(MyMessage, message_types.VoidMessage,
                    ...)
  def my_method(self, request):
    ...
    return message_types.VoidMessage()
```

This currently returns a 200 on the development server, thanks for finding this bug!

Comment: That would be the same as returning null in Java doesn't it? Looks like on production that also returns 204.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't help, but the only way I know to manipulate the status code is by raising an exception. There are a default set of exceptions provided which map to 400, 401, 403, 404 and 500. The docs say you can [subclass endpoints.ServiceException](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/exceptions) to generate other status codes, however I haven't been able to get this to work. If you set http_status to anything other than one of those listed above, it always results in a 400.

```
class TestException(endpoints.ServiceException):
    http_status = httplib.NO_CONTENT
```

I run a test in my handler like this:

```
raise TestException('The status should be 204')
```

And I see this output when testing it using the API explorer:

```
400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "The status should be 204"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The status should be 204"
 }
}
```

Comment: This is a fine way to do this. Care to create a subclass, or shall I in another answer?

Comment: @bossylobster - glad to hear it's the right way. I haven't been able to get it to work though. I'll put my example above and you can tell me if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You can make a `204` by using `protorpc.message_types.VoidMessage` as your response type and simply using `return protorpc.message_types.VoidMessage()`. Feel free to update your answer accordingly. Thanks for making me dig for this. It seems Google's API Infrastructure only supports a restricted subset of status codes (`418 I'm a teapot` also not supported, I checked). I'll check with the team on this and hope to report more.

Comment: Interesting - VoidMessage was actually my first thought, but when I tested it in the local dev server it returned a 200. I just tried it after deploying live and it does indeed return 204. Thanks - you should add an answer with this, I'll leave all this here in case it helps anyone else.